# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Timeout while reading response from Server) Node.js,Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, timeout, multer, http-status-code-504

While trying to upload large files, I am getting 504 timeout error. Using node.js/multer , cloudflare , nginx , ec2. the network is not that great and it takes time to upload the file, getting timeout after 4-7 minutes into the upload. was not spotting an exact same timeout periods, it is always random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to Cloudflare free package that limits you from uploading files greater than 50mb.

Answer (score 0):

In your Nginx configurations for the server, probably you need to change the limit at

```
client_max_body_size 5M;
```

to something like 10M or whatever your max file size is

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```

plus if using nginx proxy increase timeout limits too

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```